# Navbar collapse toggle button does not work in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently experiencing an issue with Bootstrap where the toggle navbar button does not want to work when it is clicked.
I have searched around trying to find a solution yet none of these seem to be working.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">PC Service Manager</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw navfa"></i>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-in navfa"></i>Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Are you linking the `bootstrap.js` or `bootstrap.min.js` files?  Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/wandyt92/

Comment: include `jquery.min.js` file before `bootstrap.min.js` file or whatever you're using.

Comment: Thanks @Emu that solved the problem, seemed that the jquery.min.js was not included.